# Is there a way to set LDAP authentication on frontend application based on angular 8?

Tags: angular, ldap, frontend

I have to develop a web application that contains some protected contents. I was said to built the authentication on front-end side, using LDAP on an angular application. I'm not sure this is possible, I don't find anything useful on internet. Is there any tutorial to do this?

Comment: You can use ASP.NET (Core) Web API with Windows Authentication

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of backend for authentication. There are 3rd party options to do this. Like [Auth0](https://auth0.com/authenticate/angular2/ldap/).

Alternatively, you can use [social authentications](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-social-login) like Facebook, Twitter or Google.